# Pre-trained transformers model for sentiment analysis in Finnish language?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, huggingface-transformers

I need to classify product reviews (positive/negative) written in Finnish language by using transformers python library. I have tried to do it with this model:
https://github.com/TurkuNLP/FinBERT

But that one only supports `fill-mask` tasks, not `sentiment-analysis` or `text-classification`. Could I have some advise on where to find suitable model? Here is my code:

```
import transformers
import torch
model = transformers.BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1") 
model.eval()
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.cuda()
tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1")
# this doesn't work, because this model does not support sentiment analysis
classifier = transformers.pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
print(classifier("Lorem ipsum text."))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have an annotated datset in Finnish, you can pretrain the model for sentiment analysis.

Comment: @Bill You mean fine-tuning? How would I do it with Huggingface/Transformers?